# System.Timer not available in Metro Apps? What can I use instead of it?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to poll the server and get JSON at regular intervals but for some reason I cannot see reference System.Timers in a blank app I am writing.
This is my code

```
public MainWindow()
{
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(CheckJson_Click_1);
    timer.Interval = 30000; //30sec*1000microsec             
    timer.Enabled = true;                       
    timer.Start();
}

private async void CheckJson_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;       
    var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("URI"));
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();      
    var component = JsonObject.Parse(result);     
}
```

Can anybody let me know what I can use instead of timer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) is usually set to raise events on ThreadPool threads. If you're using that now, you'll want to use the new [`ThreadPoolTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230587.aspx) class.

If you want to raise events on the UI thread instead, you'll want the new [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx), the replacement for [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).

**Edit:** Your comments indicate that you want to use a DispatcherTimer, but you're having trouble with the code. Here's a straight translation of what you've got in the comments:

```c#
public void StartTimer(object o, RoutedEventArgs sender)
{ 
    this.timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    // this is an easier way to specify TimeSpan durations
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);

    // you don't need the delegate wrapper
    timer.Tick += checkJson_Tick;

    timer.Start();
}

void checkJson_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is my code now `public void StartTimer(object o, RoutedEventArgs sender)
        {
            this.timer = new DispatcherTimer():
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100); // 100 Milliseconds 
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(CheckJson_Click_1);
            timer.Start();
        }`      But i have an error which says cannot convert system.eventhandler to system.eventhandler<object> . I am sort of confused now. Thanks

Comment: I have the following error now -`Error 1 No overload for 'CheckJson_Click1' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler<object>`

Comment: Change the signature of `CheckJson_Click1` to match what `DispatcherTimer` expects. Look to my sample for guidance. Please also read the documentation for `DispatcherTimer`, linked from my answer.